# Python numpy multidimensional array filtering by another array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, mask

I have a list consisting of 7 columns and over 43 thousand rows, representing x,y,z,R,G,B, Intensity of a point cloud from a LIDAR survey. I would like to filter the cloud by color, having manually isolated a portion. I would like to eliminate all the rows that do not have the RGB combination equal to one of those present in the filter.
For example:

```
Data=[[4,8,12,179,118,74,I1], [5,10,45,142,186,98,I2], [7,14,21,185,193,112,I3], [8,16,24,115,140,43,I3]]
```

And I have a filter on columns 4, 5, and 6 (RGB), as follows:

```
Filter=[[179,118,74],[185,193,112]]
```

As output, I would like to get a new list containing only the items that meet the prerequisites (in this case they would be the first and third row).
I would like a new list of this kind:

```
newlist=[[4,8,12,179,118,74,I1], [7,14,21,185,193,112,I3]]
```

I have no experience in Python, so I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Can you please show your desired output in code and your attempts?

Comment: will the input remain the same all throughout the process? or will it change throughout the program's run time? (e.g the lists will have 1 element less at some point in time or one element more)

Comment: What are *I1*, *I2* ...? Strings, variables? Please include a [MRE] and clarify if you want a `numpy` (like your title and tags suggest) or a `list` solution.

Comment: The input is a txt file with 7 columns and 43000 rows and in the filter 3 columns and 800 rows. Once initialised, they are never used until the moment of filtering, when I would like to eliminate all the rows in which the colour is not in the filter. As far as the solution is concerned, I would prefer to use numpy but one with lists would also be fine.

Comment: With `numpy` if *Data* is a `np.array`: `Data[np.isin(Data[:,3:6], Filter).all(1)]`

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution in comments:

```
Data[np.isin(Data[:, 3:6], Filter).all(axis=1)]
```

Indeed, `np.isin` is the most advisable option for you in such kind of problems.

I'm pretty sure it works faster if you reduce dimension of your `Data` and `Filter` before using `np.isin` in one of these ways:

```
def numpy_dimreduce_ravel(arr, shape):
    return np.ravel_multi_index(arr.T, shape, order='F')

def numpy_dimreduce_dot(arr, shape):
    dim_shape = np.cumprod(np.insert(shape[:-1], 0, 1))
    return np.dot(arr, dim_shape)
Data = np.array([[4,8,12,179,118,74], [5,10,45,142,186,98], [7,14,21,185,193,112], [8,16,24,115,140,43]])
shape = (256, 256, 256)

new_Data = numpy_dimreduce_ravel(data[:,3:6], shape) #[4880051, 6470286, 7389625, 2854003]
# or:
new_Data = numpy_dimreduce_dot(data[:,3:6], shape) #[4880051, 6470286, 7389625, 2854003]
# and:
new_Filter = numpy_dimreduce_ravel(Filter, shape) #[4880051, 7389625]
```

So you're able to do it in a more flexible way now:

```
>>> Data[np.isin(new_data, new_Filter)]
array([[  4,   8,  12, 179, 118,  74],
       [  7,  14,  21, 185, 193, 112]])
```